# Load .html file from public folder and parse php variables to it without using blade tags or php syntax

Tags: php, html, parsing

So guys, I am trying to load a .HTML view from my public folder as well as display the necessary variables in it. I am trying to not have any script on this file and that is why it's extension is .html and not .blade.php or .ph. My question is, how do I display my variables without blade tags or . The str_replace displays it statically by replacing the name permanently in the file.
This below is what my controller looks like presently;

`

```
public function showDetail($id)
    {
        $event = Event::find($id);
        $name = $event->event_name;
        $template = Template::where('id', $event->template_id)->first();
        $content = File::get($template->file_path);
        $contents = str_replace(array('name'), array( $name), $content);
        file_put_contents($template->file_path, $contents);
        View::addExtension('html', 'php');
        return File::get( $template->file_path);
    }
```

Comment: i think you need .htaccess for that

Comment: It wouldn't be very efficient, I think, but you could have the PHP generate unique HTML files that are static by writing the file completely from a template rather than trying to pass in variables during render time. If you are looking to have the HTML file act as a template and pass in values, HTML can't do that with out some sort of scripting language (usually JavaScript).

Comment: I am working in a laravel project presently, Please of what need will .htaccess be?

Comment: @McRed I am well aware javascript can do it perfectly, but the product owner specifically wants it done with php and . HTML/css template

Comment: @Worldwayii So the requirement is that you must use PHP, but can't have PHP tags on the view? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @McRed Yes, That's the requirement